# SQL Join two table with key into different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table, in SQL; the first table(T1) is this:

```
ID  
----
401 
402
403
634
635
636
```

The second table(T2) is this:

```
ID1 | VALUE1 | ID2 | VALUE2
---- -------- ----- -------
401 | TEST   | 634 | SAMPLE1
402 | MYVAL  | 635 | TRUE
```

The result i need is this:

```
T1.ID | T2.ID1| T2.VALUE1 | T2.ID2 | T2.VALUE2
------ ------- ----------- -------- ----------
401   | 401   | TEST      | 634    | SAMPLE1
402   | 402   | MYVAL     | 635    | TRUE
634   | 401   | TEST      | 634    | SAMPLE1
635   | 402   | MYVAL     | 635    | TRUE
```

The value 403 and 636 of T1 must not be present in the result because don't have any reference in T2.

There is a way to accomplish this with some INNER JOIN? I'm using MS SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you can do simple join tables like this:

```
select t1.id, t2.id1, t2.value1, t2.id2, t2.value2
from t1
join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id1 or t1.id = t2.id2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this just be in `IN` clause?

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID IN (T2.ID1,T2.ID2)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ed15aaf479cff733e4d36ac047a72ed)

Answer (score 1):

You need `INNER JOIN` AND `UNION`. Try like

```
(SELECT T1.ID , T2.ID1, T2.VALUE1 , T2.ID2 , T2.VALUE2 FROM
  T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = T2.ID1)
UNION 
(SELECT T1.ID , T2.ID1, T2.VALUE1 , T2.ID2 , T2.VALUE2 FROM
  T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = T2.ID2)
```

Comment: No, you don't. You just need a simple `OR` or `IN` in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OR` in your `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID1, T2.VALUE1, T2.ID2, T2.VALUE2
    FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID1 OR T1.ID = T2.ID2
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e5bb2/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with belwo query:

```
SELECT T1.ID , T2.ID1, T2.VALUE1 , T2.ID2 , T2.VALUE2
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table1 T2 ON T1.ID IN (T2.ID1,T2.ID2)
WHERE T2.ID1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this query output what you need?

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID1, t2.VALUE1, t2.ID2, t2.VALUE2
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID1

UNION

SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID1, t2.VALUE1, t2.ID2, t2.VALUE2
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select v.id, t2.*
from table2 t2 cross apply
     (values (t2.id1), (t2.id2)) as v(id);
```

I don't see what `table1` has to do with the result set.  Hence, `join` does not seem very useful.

Comment: Table1 is the resulset of a select; i need to join the resulset(T1) with the T2 table; what you do is to put the T2 ID in the first column but i don't need this.

Comment: @MrTex . . . This is what your data suggests that you actually want.